# Is amazon RDS charge increase on database volume

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud, rds

Suppose I have a database in amazon RDS with 100 data available. Now I made a query to fetch a single data from these 100 data. After few days this 100 data become 100k data and now I made same query again to fetch a single data. Now here is my question-> is my query cost will be same for both? Or second one will be higher than first one?

Comment: Seems kind of off-topic since this is a programming forum not a financial planning forum

Comment: Read the [Amazon RDS price list](https://aws.amazon.com/it/rds/pricing/) it's to difficult?

Comment: Yes...RDS price is more difficult then machine language

Comment: They have also a ["SIMPLE" Montly Calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#s=RDS), but I don't know if you will need to hire an expert to use it. Good luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

RDS [pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/) is based on the cost of the hourly RDS instance class, plus the cost of storage and backups, and for some database types (Aurora) there is an I/O rate cost. Other than the I/O rate, the pricing is pretty straight-forward and should answer your question.